# How to specify BinaryReader to interpret as big-endian

Tags: c#

Is there a way to tell the BinaryReader to interpret as big-endian? Like just saying "interpret everything big endian" so I don't have to write extra code to manually read in bytes, reverse them, and then convert it to int or float or whatever I need.

UPDATE

looked around, seems like you can't.

Which is kind of strange; I figured it's something you'd naturally do when writing a class that will read binary data from arbitrary files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<strike>Try creating a BinaryReader [BinaryReader(stream,encoding)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/663y489y.aspx) using the [Encoding.BigEndianUnicode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.encoding.bigendianunicode.aspx) Property</strike>

Since it was pointed out that this is for text only, you will have to create your own code to manually convert it, or you can use Scott Chamberlain's  example at the end of this [MSDN Forum Posting](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/netfxbcl/thread/a9ef76e2-42a4-4e9e-baf8-52508fd6d3a4) .

Comment: Thanks, but that's only for strings. Would be nice if microsoft provided such an option for the rest of the methods though so it would take less effort to read big-endian files.